# Can I pass along all properties when for a GradleBuild task?

Tags: build, gradle, build.gradle

I'm executing a `GradleBuild` task, and I'd like to maintain all the properties that the *current* script has been given. In other words, I want to package up "these startparameters" and pass them along to the build I'm calling.

Is there any way to do this cleanly?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "all the properties that the current script has been given"?

Comment: I think I mean `project.gradle.startParameter`... which might just answer my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you mean project properties:

```
task foo(type: GradleBuild) {
    startParameter.projectProperties = gradle.startParameter.projectProperties
}
```

If you mean system properties, replace `projectProperties` with `systemPropertiesArgs` (on both sides).

Comment: any ways to pass in the task arguments ?